# How to set rules (custom text) for issues in Github?

Tags: github, github-issues

Sometimes when creating an issue on Github, there is some text in place to describe what the repository Authors expect of any issues that are created.

If you have a repository and want to add this custom text so people creating issues can read it, how do you do that (add the custom text)?

Only if possible, I would like the custom text to appear *without*:

- new files appearing in the repo (which could distract if the repo is a an MRE or tutorial). I.e. none of this:

[image]

- anything else being added (e.g. like contact links produced with the [example](https://docs.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/configuring-issue-templates-for-your-repository) yml)

```
blank_issues_enabled: false
contact_links:
  - name: GitHub Community Support
    url: https://github.community/
    about: Please ask and answer questions here.
  - name: GitHub Security Bug Bounty
    url: https://bounty.github.com/
    about: Please report security vulnerabilities here.
```

Comment: Hey! Are you talking about creating a template for your issue - https://docs.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/configuring-issue-templates-for-your-repository

Comment: @Dheeraj I updated the question with a couple more criteria, which may or may not be possible - I ask in hope it is possible

Comment: I will have a look if this is possible, haven't done it like this before.

Comment: @Dheeraj I might be asking for the impossible. The reason I wish to prevent new files cluttering the UI, is because the repository is a tutorial with only 3 files, and the extra file will cause confusion for new comers (and the file looks scary because there's a dot in it, capital letters, and `.github` is a different colour to the rest. Makes complete sense to anyone who's used some github before, but distracting for new comers who are already at their cognitive limit

Answer (score 1):

GitHub already has [a guide](https://docs.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/configuring-issue-templates-for-your-repository) on how to make issue templates & creating a template chooser similar to what you described.

Comment: Thanks, will check it out. Seems unintuitive that it's not under issues, but under settings/templates etc. But I guess there's more than just templates for issues, so I can see why github put them all together in one place

Comment: I have updated the question, what I am after may not be possible but I thought I'd ask and see